# Do private collaboration platform really need private file access?

Tags: performance

I need to make private collaboration platform, where the website is not open to public registration, and all the posts is only accessible by the members.

The members is management team of a company. Along with many features, it has Announcement. When posting Announcement, it has option to upload images.

I personally like it public, because the file transfer faster and can be easily integrated with CDN.

I just wonder whether I need to make the image public, or only accessible by the members.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your environment is very similar to other collaboration tools, such as [HipChat](https://www.hipchat.com/).

What HipChat does, is to generate a random and unique prefix for every file you upload (preserving the original name), so that it's very hard to guess the value.
Files are made public and served via Amazon S3.

I think it's a reasonable choice. If you choose to use Amazon S3, you can also store files as protected and generate an access key on the fly to allow the user access to it.